# How Can I Get Device Id

Tags: jquery, mobile

I use Jquery mobile instead of cordova. How can I get device id by uisng Jquery or pure javascript?

I found some solutions but all of them are about cordova. I dont want to use cordova.

edit: I mean unique id. User will login, and close the application (not logout) then open again. The application have to know which user come to. Mobile devicec dont have cockie or session.

Comment: why not codova? Cordova and phonegap are two different things. Phonegap just uses the cordova lib for themself and can also be implemented on a normal webpage

Comment: because I dont know cordova. And I dont have enough time

Comment: Then should probably use localStorage, like @Der Vampyr adviced.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `device id`? If you want to know which device is used you can check it like this:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  isMobileDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|webOS)/);
}

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  isIpad = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)/);
}
```

Comment: Remember userAgent sniffing is considered very shaky grounds to enter

Comment: Well, i didn´t know that. Why is there a problem with it?

Comment: Thanks, but I mean unique id. User will login, and close the application (not logout) then open again. The application have to know which user come to. Mobile devicec dont have cockie or session.

Comment: Mobile devices have a local storage you can use like a cookie,

Comment: userAgent has been misused by browser vendors before (mimicking each other), could happen again.